# Flash Player 10.1 for Flash Professional CS4 playerglobal.swc?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Adobe released projector, debugger and plugin for Flash 10.1 yesterday.  on my Mac i've installed the standalone player and debugger in Adobe Flash CS4/Players/ and Adobe Flash CS4/Players/Debug respectively.

however, i think i need to download the globalplayer.swc for 10.1 so that Flash CS4 IDE is directed to use the new players.

i've searched but i could only find the globalplayer.swc that was released during the 10.1 betas, and i'm not sure if that's the .swc i should use for the final 10.1 release.

Adobe's site doesn't mention anything about replacing the .swc to use 10.1 in CS4, so i'm not sure if it's necessary.

i've tried creating actionscripts to include flash.ui.Multitouch and flashx.textLayout and neither can be found.  i have no idea how to make Flash Professional CS4 use the new APIs available in Flash Player 10.1

suggestions?

---

**FRAME SCRIPT:**

```
import flash.ui.Multitouch;

var myTextField:TextField = new TextField();
myTextField.width = 200;

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterhandler);

function enterhandler(e:Event):void
    {
    var support:Boolean = Multitouch.supportsTouchEvents;
    switch  (support)
            { 
            case true:  myTextField.text = "Touch events supported"; 
                        break; 

            case false: myTextField.text = "Touch events not supported"; 
                        break; 

            default:    myTextField.text = "unknown"; 
            }

    addChild(myTextField);
    }
```

**ERROR:** (continuous enter frame event error)

```
ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable flash.ui::Multitouch is not defined.
    at multitouchtest_fla::MainTimeline/enterhandler()
ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable flash.ui::Multitouch is not defined.
    at multitouchtest_fla::MainTimeline/enterhandler()
ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable flash.ui::Multitouch is not defined.
    at multitouchtest_fla::MainTimeline/enterhandler()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the official playerglobal.swc for Flash Player 10.1 from the Flex 4.1 SDK:
http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Download+Flex+4

It's in the frameworks/libs/player/10.1 directory.

Also you can check if the device supports gestures and touch using these statics:
[Multitouch.supportsGestureEvents](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/ui/Multitouch.html?allClasses=1#supportsGestureEvents)
[Multitouch.supportsTouchEvents](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/ui/Multitouch.html?allClasses=1#supportsTouchEvents)

Comment: hi james.  i've downloaded the Flex 4.1 SDK, and placed it's 10.1 globalplayer.swc into /applications/adobe flash cs4/common/configuration/actionscript 3.0/FP10 and the new APIs are still not recognized.  when testing for Multitouch.supportsGestureEvents, i receive this error:  ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable flash.ui::Multitouch is not defined."  what other settings do i need to change so that CS4 recognizes the new APIs in 10.1?

Comment: Is that error a runtime error or compile-time error?  If it's runtime then you don't have Flash Player 10.1 installed.

Comment: it's a runtime error, but i certainly have 10.1. in applications/adobe flash cs4/players i have both projector and debug versions 10.1.53.64.  i just displaced the /players folder and restarted flash to see if it requires this folder.  test movie still operates, which leads me to believe it's calling a different flash player somewhere.  finally, my advanced actionscript 3.0 settings lists only "$(AppConfig)/ActionScript 3.0/libs" under library path.  is that correct?

Comment: What version does this page say you have?
http://www.adobe.com/software/flash/about/

Comment: 10,1,81,3 installed.  which seems a bit ridiculous according to the latest available version 10.1.53.64 in the chart below.  i'm on a mac.  Safari and Chrome both say the 10,1,81,3 installed.

Comment: for clarity, i'm aware that Multitouch doesn't work in browsers on Mac, but i feel that i should be able to still test for them, using supportsGestureEvents function, as well as other new APIs from Flash Professional CS4's test movie player, without publishing for the web.

Comment: You might want to uninstall that version and reinstall the official latest.

Comment: ok.  so now i have used adobe's uninstaller to remove the bizarre 10,1,81,3 version and have successfully installed 10,1,53,64.  while doing so seems to have fixed flash in Chrome browser (it was so buggy i switched back to Safari), i'm still receiving runtime errors with the simple script i've taken from the documentation.  i've added the code to my original post with the runtime error.

Comment: it seems to work in both browsers.  "Touch events not supported" is displayed.  however, i still receive runtime errors when testing within Flash Pro CS4.  i'm thinking i need to publish an Air app to make it work on my MacBook with trackpad, but adobe only offers Air 2.0 as part of a Flash Pro CS5 update.  i've been successful with testing textFlow inside Flash Pro CS4, but i had to manually move the textLayout.swc from the Flex 4.1 SDK into my $(AppConfig)/ActionScript 3.0/libs folder.  i thought it would automatically be included since the Flex 4.1 SDK folder is also in that folder.

Comment: Perhaps when you are launching it from CS4 it is launching it in a standalone Flash Player.  Maybe you need to update that Flash Player.  You could try to locate "flashplayer" and then run it and see what version it is.

Comment: that was what i did first weeks ago when this problem started.  i downloaded both the projector and debugger of Flash Player 10.1.53.64 and placed them in /Adobe Flash CS4/Players/.  however, if i place the /players/ folder in the trash temporarily and restart flash, i can still test.  so if Flash CS4 isn't using the projector or debugger in the /players/ folder, what does it use?  i've searched my HD and there are no other players other than those in the /players/ folder and the internet plugin.

Comment: Can you see what version of the projector is being launched from CS4?

Comment: i don't know how.  i mean, it's just a new window of Flash Professional CS4.

Comment: You could output it in the app using Capabilities.version.

Comment: this is the problem.  tracing the capabilities version has returned "MAC 10,0,22,91"!  so now how am i suppose to replace this with the 10.1?

Comment: You should be able to update the Flash Player somewhere in the <drive>Applications:Adobe Flash CS4 folder.

Comment: i agree.  however, as instructed by adobe's website, i've updated all Flash Player versions in the /players/ folder to 10.1.53.64 but the application isn't using any of these players.  i can not find the version 10.0.22.91 that the application is using for testing movies.

Comment: I'm out of ideas.  Perhaps you need to contact Adobe Support.

Comment: James, if you're still following this thread, i assumed that CS5 would have fixed this issue, but it doesn't.  the following site perfectly explains the problem for both Flash CS4 and CS5.  http://swfhead.com/blog/?p=575

Comment: Bummer.  Hopefully this gets more attention now and someone from the Flash CS5 team responds.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether it's up to date but it's at least for 10.1 beta:
http://labs.adobe.com/downloads/flashplayer10.html

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues with my Flash CS4, recently i have found one important link for that check out 
http://swfhead.com/blog/?p=709
http://swfhead.com/blog/?p=133

hope it helps... :)