# Targeting Flash Player 10.3 in Adobe Flash CS5

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs5

Has anyone successfully tried using Microphone.getEnhancedMicrophone() method in Adobe Flash CS5?

I tried all these steps;

```
Step 1: Go to the locaiton C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash CS5\Common\Configuration\ActionScript 3.0
Step 2: Create a new folder with the name "FP10.3"
Step 3: Copy the file and paste it in the following location:
            C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash CS5\Common\Configuration\ActionScript 3.0\FP10.3
Step4: Rename the swc name to "playerglobal.swc"

Step 5: Goto the following location C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash CS5\Common\Configuration\Players
Step 6: Create a copy of "FlashPlayer10_1.xml" and rename as "FlashPlayer10_3.xml"
Step 7: Open it in an editor and change according to below:
             <player id="FlashPlayer10.3" version="12" asversion="3">
   <name>Flash Player 10.3</name>
   <path builtin="true"/>
   <path platform="WIN">Device Central/adcdl.exe</path>
   <path platform="MAC">Device Central/adcdl</path>
   <playerDefinitionPath as2="$(UserConfig)/Classes/FP10;$(UserConfig)/Classes/FP9;$(UserConfi g)/Classes/FP8;$(UserConfig)/Classes/FP7" as3="$(AppConfig)/ActionScript 3.0/FP10.3/playerglobal.swc" />

Step 8: Close the flash application if launched and restart the flash application.
Step 9: If you promptly followed everything you will Flash player 10.3 in the target players from the publish settings and change your target to flash player 10.3.
Step 10: Now import two statements:

          import flash.media.Microphone;
          import flash.media.MicrophoneEnhancedMode;
```

Yet, now when I try to call the function Microphone.getEnhancedMicrophone() I get an error - `TypeError: Error #1006: getEnhancedMicrophone is not a function`

After googling a bit, I figured out that I need to compile it using `-swf-version=12` as arguments, but that seems to work with flex, I cannot figure out how would it work with Flash CS5.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i had a similar problem moving to Flash Professional CS4 with Player 10.1 a while back:  [Flash Player 10.1 for Flash Professional CS4 playerglobal.swc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3021930/flash-player-10-1-for-flash-professional-cs4-playerglobal-swc)

are you compiling your program with "Test Movie"?  try "Debug Movie" instead.

Test Movie uses a built-in Flash player (or it at least use to do so) that is, regrettably, not updatable.  you can determine it's version by running the following with Test Movie:

```
import flash.system.Capabilities;

trace(Capabilities.version);
```

Debug Movie will compile and launch your project with the debug player residing in your `FlashCS5 > Players` folder and since that target player is 10.3 you should not receive anymore errors.

Comment: Cool. Thanks. So, when I publish it and view it in browser, it should work fine?

Comment: yes, but you can still test either with "Debug Movie" (Command + Shift + Return) or but publishing and running your .swf in the standalone Flash Player